# How to convert timezone in ADF to CST

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline

I need to write a file name which includes the current time in CST. how can I convert the timezone into CST in a file name of ADF.

Let me know if anyone knows the solution. There are numerous function to convert in UTC in ADF but my requirement is to convert into CST and for that there is no such function I can find.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by CST? There are multiple time zones that use the abbreviation "CST", and if you mean "US Central Time" that's not quite the same thing, as it varies between CST and CDT. Additionally, is this question *really* specific to ADF and creating a file name, or is it just "How do I obtain the current date/time in a specific time zone"?

Answer (score 0):

These are the [timezones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11#time-zones) that ADF expression follows. Go through those and use the time zone as per your requirement.

Use the below expression in a set variable activity. Here for sample I have given `IST`.

```
@concat(convertFromUtc(utcnow(), 'India Standard Time'),'.csv')
```

**Result**:

[image]

You need to use Dataset parameter for your dataset file name and give the above variable for it.